# malloc with huge multidimensional arrays, failing for a neuroscience sim

Tags: arrays, visual-c++, memory, malloc, multidimensional-array

I'm setting up a very large array to handle a primitive neuron simulation. New[] craps out when assigning memory (about 8-9 Gig) for the array. I was able to get C-style malloc to reserve the memory, but as soon as I try to assign a value, I get an Access violation reading location 0xffffffffffffffff.

I'm running 64-bit Windows 7, with Visual Studio 2010 Professional. I've tried malloc and new[] with nested loops as well and they crash also.

If this is impossible for malloc to do, what else should I consider? I need something that can access large memory spaces very fast. Thank you for your consideration.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int nRows;
int nCols;
int nDepth;
int nData;

int main()
{
        //unsigned long int brainSize=100;
        //nRows = int(pow(brainSize,0.3333333333333333333333333333))+1;
            nRows=80;
        nCols=nRows; 
        nDepth=nRows;
        nData=2000;

        double brainData = nRows*nCols*nDepth*nData;
        double brainBits = 4*brainData;
        cout.imbue(std::locale(""));
        cout << fixed << "Brain size : " << nRows*nCols*nDepth << " neurons \nBrain integers : " << setprecision(0) << brainData << "\nBrain bits: " << brainBits << endl;

    __int64 ****brain;
    brain =  (__int64 ****)malloc(nRows*nCols*nDepth*nData*sizeof(__int64 ****));
        cout << "Brain initialized.";
        brain [2][2][2][2]=2; // error is here. 
        cout << brain[2][2][2][2];


    int breaker;
    cin >> breaker; //pause
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

A few things to think about:

- Are you sure that you are creating a 64-bit executable? Just running on
- How much free memory is available (this includes both physical and swap)
- What type do you pass to `malloc`? Make sure you use `size_t` and not `int`
- Maybe [`VirtualAlloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366887%28VS.85%29.aspx) will work (that limits your program to Windows though)

You might want to consider using a memory-mapped file instead. Instead of allocating all of the memory yourself, you allocate it but it is backed by the file. The operating system then worries about making sure that when you access it (which you do as if it were regular `new`/`malloc`'d memory) it is available for you. If there is enough physical RAM available, it might keep the whole thing in memory, otherwise it will page bits in as needed.

In general a memory mapped file is going to work better, since that should always work, even on systems with less memory. And it will allow for much higher memory usage. Sure, you *could* probably build your own caching scheme (keeping some stuff in memory, other stuff on disk), but operating system designers are pretty good at these things, so since that probably isn't your main goal (building a caching system) you might as well let the OS do its job.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've 12 Gig of DDR3 memory available; the array as posted is <95% of available. . I've shrunk the array values to take up less than 20% of RAM; crash is the same. It seems to do this primarily when the fourth dimension (nData) is considerably >> than the rest. I probably can't use the disk as I'll be farming out portions of the 'brain' to asynchronous CPU threads or more likely GPU cores later on. I added size_t as you suggested, but receive the same crash? I replaced the line with: brain =  (__int64 ****)malloc (size_t(nRows*nCols*nDepth*nData*sizeof(__int64 ****)));

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are declaring a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to 64-bit integer, not a four-dimensional array of 64-bit integers. When you dereference it with a chain of `[2][2][2][2]`, the compiler looks up a pointer in an uninitialized block that you have just allocated, tries to dereference it, and promptly crashes.

If your at least three of the four sizes (say, `nRows`, `nColumns`, and `nDepth`) were compile-time constants, you could allocate `nData` 3-D arrays, and use the regular square-bracket syntax to access elements. If that is not possible, you'll either have to live with the overhead of pointers, or allocate a "plain" array and implement your own addressing scheme into it to make believe it's 4-D.

P.S. I am silently assuming here that the overhead of using `vector<...>` is prohibitive in your situation. If you have enough memory for the additional pointers, though, I'd definitely go for a vector of vectors of vectors of vectors of 64-bit integers: it is fast, it is reliable, and it is easy to use.

**EDIT :** This is what you can do if three of the four dimensions are constants:

```
#include <iostream>

const int nRows = 11;
const int nColumns = 13;
const int nDepth = 17;

typedef long long brain_block[nRows][nColumns][nDepth];

int main() {
    int nData = 123;
    brain_block *brain = (brain_block*)malloc(nData*sizeof(brain_block));
    memset(brain, 0, nData*sizeof(brain_block));
    brain[2][2][2][2] = 2;
    std::cout << brain[2][2][2][2] << std::endl;
    free(brain);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have to avoid vector<> as I'd like to squeeze every possible byte of RAM into the simulated brain - the requirements for large nets are enormous. The simplest point-neuron requires around 7 terabytes if scaled up to a human neocortex. So speed and the lowest footprint are vital. May you elaborate on the nData 3-D array idea? All the variables save that one(Row/Column/Depth) can be made constant. nData stores  connection data between the neuron and other neurons (2,000 per), connection strengths (excitatory/inhibitory), and the neuron's excitement state. Thank you!

Comment: @ScienceDilletante I edited the answer to include an example of what to do if row/column/depth are constants.